# How can a subclass be safely converted to a parent class in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

There is a subclass that inherits from a normal superclass and a superclass with a virtual function.When I convert subclass pointer to normal superclass pointer,it will work correctly.But when I use a another superclass pointer to point subclass, then convert pointer to this normal superclass, it will print a wrong answer.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base{
public:
    virtual bool test1() = 0;
};

class base2{
public:
    int a;

    base2(int p) : a(p) {}
};

class son:public base, public base2 {
public:
    bool test1() {
        return true;
    }
    son(int p) : base2(p) {}
};

void out(base2* p) {
    cout << p -> a;
}

int main()
{
    
    /* if I use this, it will print a wrong number,such as -1359748056
     base * o = new son(9);
     out((base2*)o);
     */
    
    /* if I use this, it will print 9
    out(new son(9));
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I dont't know Why.Converting a subclass to a parent class isn't safe?

Comment: **Cringe** Never define a base class without a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote in the line

```cpp
out((base2*)o);
```

is called a C-style cast or a [reinterpret_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast). You should almost never do that when dealing with classes and object because it just changes the type of the pointer without taking care of adjusting the virtual table locations. For that reason it prints garbage, because it is looking at the wrong field offset.

Ideally you should use [static cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) as in

```cpp
out( static_cast<base2*>(o) );
```

However `base` and `base2` are not directly related by inheritance so static_cast throws out a compiler error. So you have to use the slower version [dynamic cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) as

```cpp
out( dynamic_cast<base2*>(o) );
```

When you write this way, the program prints

```
Program stdout
99
```

[Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vMoejoxh3)